# React redux useSelector best practice

Tags: react-redux, hook

Learning redux/react-redux, I'm using useSelector with inner selector function in a separate file. It's working perfectly but I have question about best practices.

Assuming that I have a state with 3 entries (firstname, lastname, email), is it better to :

**1. Have a specific selector for each case?**

*selector.js*

```
export const selectFirstname = (state) => state.currentUser.firstName
export const selectLastname = (state) => state.currentUser.lastName
export const selectEmail = (state) => state.currentUser.email
```

*component.js*

```
const firstName = useSelector(selectFirstname)
const lastName = useSelector(selectLastname )
const email = useSelector(selectEmail)
```

**2. Have a generic selector with param?**

*selector.js*

```
export const selectItem = (key) => {
  return (state) => state.currentUser[key]
}
```

*component.js*

```
const firstName = useSelector(selectItem('firstName'))
const lastName = useSelector(selectItem('lastName'))
const email = useSelector(selectItem('email'))
```

**3. Have a global selector and use it with destructuring in my component?**

*selector.js*

```
export const selectItem = (state) => state.currentUser
```

*component.jsx*

```
const {firstName, lastName, email} = useSelector(selectItem)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: 3rd one I use most often and it makes it much easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you Faisal. It's a modern, short notation, and as you say, easy to handle, it makes perfect sense now. I was too focused on getting as many specific selectors as possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't be doing #3. You should be returning the smallest amounts of data per the docs: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-multiple-selectors-in-a-component

So 1 or 2 is your best option. Also, anytime `currentUser` changes the whole thing will re-render and if you are only using 3 of the values, why re-render the component when the values have not changed.